# Bouncing scroll affecting UITableview Content?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, scroll, bounce

I am having a really weird issue related to `scrolling` a `UITableView`.

I have a `TableView` populated with a `collection` of `MPMediaItems`: songs in an album. In IB, I have an `UIImageView` that is intended to show an `indicator` if the song is stored in the cloud. When the `TableView` `cell` is populated, I check if the song is `iCloud`, if not the `UIImageView` is removed entirely and if so then the `ImageView` is assigned an `image`:

```
UIImageView *isCloudIcon = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:105];

if ([[rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem] boolValue] == NO) {
    [isCloudIcon removeFromSuperview];
} else if ([[rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem] boolValue] == YES) {
    isCloudIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iCloudIcon.png"];
}
```

This displays initially just fine, but it's also where the weirdness starts. If *all* songs are stored locally, everything works just fine. Likewise if *all* songs are stored in the cloud, everything works. But if it is a combination then it will display correctly initially, but as you `scroll up` and`down`, the `iCloud` icon `image` views begin to magically disappear. Just through playing with it, I've been able to determine that it is related to bouncing scroll. Every time the TableView bounces on scroll it removes an `ImageView`, seemingly for no reason. Turning off bounce solves the problem, but this is jarring and I'd prefer to leave it in.

Has anyone encountered behaviour like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is from your `UITableViewCell` sub class?
If so, your problem is not concerned about bouncing, but the problem is `UITableViewCell` with `isCloudIcon` removed is reused.

You should hide them instead of remove.

The code shold be:

```
if ([[rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem] boolValue] == NO) {
    isCloudIcon.hidden = YES;
} else if ([[rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem] boolValue] == YES) {
    isCloudIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iCloudIcon.png"];
    isCloudIcon.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Sigh, you are obviously correct. This solves it. Of course it breaks my workaround for another issue, but isn't that always the way...